# Ethernet connection lost and shows "not connected" after wake-up from sleep

Tags: ethernet

Warning: I'm a novice. 
I've installed 18.04 on my laptop (dual boot with Windows 10). I'm trying to use Ethernet. This works OK when I boot but after laptop sleeps and wakes up the connection is lost and Network Settings reports "not connected"
I tried Network Manager restart from the Terminal but that doesn't work. (Also tried this with WiFi switched off)
I also tried editing the Network Manager so ifupdown managed = true but that made no difference.
Any help appreciated but please don't assume too much knowledge!
Thanks

Here's the result from lshw - C network

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
   version: 05
   serial: b8:70:f4:d9:11:52
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
   resources: iomemory:ffffffff0-fffffffef iomemory:ffffffff0-fffffffef irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: wlp6s0
   version: 01
   serial: 00:26:5e:58:67:64
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.3.0-46-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:17 memory:d1500000-d150ffff
```

kim@kim-Satellite-C660:~$ lspci -nn

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller [8086:0044] (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller [8086:3b64] (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b3c] (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [8086:3b56] (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:3b42] (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:3b44] (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b34] (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM55 Chipset LPC Interface Controller [8086:3b09] (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller [8086:3b29] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller [8086:3b30] (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem [8086:3b32] (rev 05)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev ff)
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
ff:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder [8086:2d01] (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 [8086:2d10] (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 [8086:2d11] (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved [8086:2d12] (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved [8086:2d13] (rev 05)


lshw -C network with ethernet definitely not working below:


sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for kim: 
  *-generic                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Illegal Vendor ID
       vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: ff
       serial: b8:70:f4:d9:11:52
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:26:5e:58:67:64
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.3.0-46-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:d1500000-d150ffff
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106685/discussion-on-question-by-kim-stilwell-ethernet-connection-lost-and-shows-not-c).

Answer (score 1):

You may possibly have multiple problems.

Your ethernet adapter may have a hardware problem. If this was a desktop computer, I'd suggest reseating the card in its slot.

When we first looked at it with `sudo lshw -C network` we saw this snippet...

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
```

But it also indicated that "link=no", which suggests a cable problem. You should be using cat 5e or cat 6 cables for gigabit connections. Yours must be an older computer, as its maximum speed appears to be only 100Mbit/s. The link problem is still a problem.

When the connection failed, we looked at `sudo lshw -C network` again, and got this snippet...

```
*-generic                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Illegal Vendor ID
   vendor: Illegal Vendor ID
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
```

Do you see the difference between the two snippets?

Although I'm not 100% sure that a different driver will operate your card, if it doesn't work, it's easy to reverse the steps.

In the `terminal`...

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install dkms r8168-dkms`

`reboot`

If the ethernet works after the reboot, you'll notice that `sudo lshw -C network` shows the driver has changed from r8169 to r8168.

If the r8168 driver isn't active, or the ethernet doesn't work at all, you'll have to...

`sudo apt-get purge r8168-dkms`

`reboot`

**Update #1:**

Consider updating your BIOS from 1.80 to 2.00. It can be downloaded from https://ie.dynabook.com/support/businesslaptops/ (just use your serial #).

**Update #2:**

You have a hardware problem with your ethernet card, or your PCI bus.